# How to find record which throws an error in a SELECT (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, date

I have a problematic SQL Sentence, when it runs

```sql
SELECT code, my_date, my_time
  FROM my_table
 WHERE to_date(to_char(my_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || my_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > sysdate - 5
```

I always get: `ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0`

This is the definition of my table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (code NUMBER(10), my_date DATE, my_time VARCHAR2(8));
ALTER TABLE  my_table ADD CONSTRAINT pk_my_table PRIMARY KEY (code);
CREATE INDEX i_my_table_001 ON my_table (my_date);
```

But If I add an extra restriction, I never get the error:

```sql
SELECT code, my_date, my_time
  FROM my_table
 WHERE my_date > trunc(sysdate - 5)
   AND to_date(to_char(my_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || my_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > sysdate - 5
```

All validations are ok. Not invalid dates, not invalid times

Is there any way to find which is the 'offending' record?

Brute force is not an option because table has more than 25M records.

Comment: Side note : `to_date(to_char(my_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || my_time), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` should be a [function based index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS254) if you run this on a daily basis against 25M line...

Comment: The parentheses aren't matched in your code, which is confusing - presumably a mistake changing the column names, but that might also be hiding a real issue. Why are you storing date and time separately?

Comment: Your data model is fundamentally flawed. In oracle a DATE (data type) contains - by definition - a time component, down to the second.  You should not have a separate column for time. Just include it with the date.  Correct that an your query becomes trivial.

Comment: I know my data model can be improved. But it means that developers must change lots of things on application code. This application has lots of tables inherited from informix with separated date and time fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Oracle 12.2 or higher, you can use the [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/DATABASE/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD) function to see which rows could be giving you an error.

#### Example Query

```
WITH
    my_table (code, my_date, my_time)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, date '2020-01-01', '08:00:00' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, date '2020-01-31', '25:00:00' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE validate_conversion (to_char(my_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || my_time AS DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = 0;
```

#### Result

```
   CODE        MY_DATE     MY_TIME
_______ ______________ ___________
      2 2020-01-31     25:00:00
```

### Update

One update that may be a bit easier than cloning your database and upgrading is to create your own function to validate the date and call that from a test SQL statement like the on below. I'm not sure if defining a function within a common table expression is supported in 12.1, but if it is not, you can make it a standalone function and call that from your query.

```
WITH
    FUNCTION validate_date (p_date DATE, p_time VARCHAR2)
        RETURN NUMBER
    AS
        l_test_date   DATE;
    BEGIN
        l_test_date :=
            TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (p_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || p_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
        RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            RETURN 0;
    END;
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS code, DATE '2020-01-01' AS my_date, '08:00:00' AS my_time FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, DATE '2020-01-31', '25:00:00' FROM DUAL) my_table
 WHERE validate_date (my_date, my_time) = 0;
```

Comment: But `my_date` is already a date, according to the question, so this would get ORA-43909 - unless you converted that to a string first, and then it depends what the actual issue is *8-) If the problem is a corrupt value in the table then that could still reveal it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It must be an issue with the time is concatenated with the date. I've updated the code.

Comment: I will take a look at VALIDATE_CONVERSION function. My database is on 12cR1 but I can make a clone and upgrade to 19c to test this.